# Memory usage of Flume MemoryChannel

Tags: java, out-of-memory, flume, flume-ng

I'm troubleshooting some memory issues I'm encountering while sending messages to Flume from some Java code.

The code runs two `EmbeddedAgent`s, each with a memory channel and some sinks pointing to a remote server.

I read in [Flume documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#memory-channel) about memory channel configurations:

> `byteCapacity`
>
> Maximum total bytes of memory allowed as a sum of all events in this channel. The implementation only counts the Event body, (...). Defaults to a computed value equal to 80% of the maximum memory available to the JVM (i.e. **80% of the -Xmx value** passed on the command line)

From what I understand this means that in worst case scenario each channel will use 80% of Xmx so 160% in my case (2 agents) which would obviously lead to OOM errors.

Am I right?

If so, I guess it means I have to setup a proper value for this configuration (not set in my current configuration) knowing that my code is actually running two memory channels?

Edit: my question assumes that `capacity` (maximum number of events in the channel) settings is quite high and the limiting factor would be the size rather than number of events.

Comment: I do not know anything about `Flume`, but that name of "Memory Channel" makes me think this is off heap they are talking about?

Comment: I don't think so from my observations but I sure can be wrong.